# how to add youtube link as an intent inside a switch case in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
spinner_links.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int p = position;
        switch (p){
            case 0:
                Intent i=new Intent()
                Toast.makeText(ShowCategory.this, "Zero Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
```

this is the code i am having how to add youtube link as an intent

Answer (score 1):

Your Intent Should be like this.

```
Intent implicit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com"));
startActivity(implicit);
```

And set permission in **AndroidManifet.xml** file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```